# C4251 warning is not produced if export member functions only

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

Such class declaration produces warning C4251 when compiled in DLL, because `std::vector<int>` is header-only and doesn't have a dll-interface:

```
#ifdef IS_DLL
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <vector>

class EXPORT Foo 
{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
private:
    std::vector<int> m_vec;
};
```

But the following declaration doesn't produce any warnings:

```
class Foo 
{
public:
    EXPORT Foo();
    EXPORT ~Foo();
private:
    std::vector<int> m_vec;
};
```

For me it's unclear why warnings are not generated in the second case (or, on the contraty, generated in the first case), because

1) `m_vec` in both examples is private so there is no possibility to access it from client code, if using correct headers (or the access is possible in both cases if use hacked headers where `private` is replaced by `public`).

2) In both cases `dumpbin /exports` command shows that only methods are exported. Output for the first version (export of the whole class):

```
1    0 00001000 ??0Foo@@QAE@ABV0@@Z = ??0Foo@@QAE@ABV0@@Z (public: __thiscall Foo::Foo(class Foo const &))
2    1 00001040 ??0Foo@@QAE@XZ = ??0Foo@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall Foo::Foo(void))
3    2 00001060 ??1Foo@@QAE@XZ = ??1Foo@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall Foo::~Foo(void))
4    3 00001020 ??4Foo@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z = ??4Foo@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z (public: class Foo & __thiscall Foo::operator=(class Foo const &))
```

and the second version (methods only):

```
1    0 00001000 ??0Foo@@QAE@XZ = ??0Foo@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall Foo::Foo(void))
2    1 00001020 ??1Foo@@QAE@XZ = ??1Foo@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall Foo::~Foo(void))
```

Could you please explain the difference between two cases and give a small example in which for the first case we have an error while for the second case everything is fine (if follow the warnings logic)?